# EditText does not detect text after fragment replace

Tags: android, authentication, android-edittext

Here's the code from Navigator.onClick(). The code in Login.onResume() seems to work, but after I do that, no matter what I type in the user id and password fields, the app doesn't seem to recognize that.  It simply keeps saying 'User id cannot be empty'.  It just works right the first time.

```
private void buttonClick(final Button btnLeft, final Button btnRight,
        final Button btnQueue) {

    btnLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            previousScreen = btnLeft.getText().toString();
            if (previousScreen.equals("Login")) {
                errorMessage = loginProcedure();
                if (errorMessage.equals("")) {
                    showDetails(btnLeft, btnRight, btnQueue,
                            fragmentTransaction);
                } else {
                    FileIO.displayMessage(getActivity(), errorMessage, null);
                }
            } else if (...) {
            }

            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

    });



private String loginProcedure() {

    errorMessage = "";
    String userID = ((EditText) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.editUserid)).getText().toString();
    if (userID.trim().equals("")) {
        errorMessage = "User ID cannot be empty";
        return errorMessage;
    }

    String password = ((EditText) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.editPassword)).getText().toString();
    if (password.trim().equals("")) {
        errorMessage = "Password cannot be empty";
        return errorMessage;
    }

    if (!FileIO.UserList.contains((userID + "PR" + password)
            .toUpperCase())) {
        errorMessage = "UnAuthorized User";
        return errorMessage;
    } else {
        userID = userID;
        UserName = password;
    }

    return errorMessage;
}
```

Comment: need to see the login fragment code

Comment: I think your missing a bit there.. I would assume you have an onClick somewhere that submits the data to the service for authentication?

Comment: @Justin I have the Login Fragment and below the Login Fragment, I have a Navigator Fragment.  The Navigator Fragment contains the Login Button.  The Login Fragment just contains the userid and password fields.  The onClick code to authenticate the user is in the Navigator Fragment.  If it is a valid user, then the Login Fragment is replaced by the First Screen of the App.  The Navigator still remains below as a way to navigate between Fragments.

Comment: can you show the onClick from the Navigator fragment?  somewhere along the line you are setting user/pass to variables and they are not getting reset by your onResume call.

Comment: @Justin I've added the code above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16896/discussion-between-justin-and-user1005585)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with your activity seeing different EditText views than is currently active on the screen. This could happen a few ways and since I can't see all of your code its hard to tell exactly whats happening.

To test change your LogIn fragment to be this:

```
public class Login extends Fragment {
    private View fragmentView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, null);
        return fragmentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        EditText e1 = (EditText) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.editUserid);
        e1.setText("");

        EditText e2 = (EditText) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        e2.setText("");
    }
}
```

This will make sure you are setting the current LogIn Fragment user and pass to "".